# Block finalization stops after nominating 4 validators

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, nominator

I am running a substrate private network on `polkadot-v0.9.36` and observed something, i.e., after nominating 4 validators from a single nominator finalization got stopped which  i didn't expected, as per the document of [polkadot](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-nominator#nominating-with-the-polkadot-js-ui) a nominator can nominate upto 16 validators but in my case it is not happening. Can anyone help in this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is related to the nominator.

Please check your validator configurations.

- Make sure you put the session keys in their keystores
- Make sure they are using different session keys
- IIRC, there is an issue that you need to restart your node once you put the GRANDPA key in its keystore; otherwise, it won't work

Comment: I have done all the things right as you said but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Can you add more detail to the question? How do you check these?